# Ajax to php wont work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to attach an event listener to a button that will make an ajax call when clicked.

I have set aside some php in a file we shall call test.php.
I have used the live jquery function to attack a click event to the button.
The ajax function will pass a value of an input element on the page to the test.php.
The test.php file will then use that value to determine the url of the file it is to use.
The test.php file dedupes the csv file based on matching emails.
The csv file is uploaded via an upload input element.

Here is my code, that is not working currently. Fiddler shows that a request is being sent out to the server but a response is not forthcoming.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="csv_dedupe" value="dedupe-file">
```

**Jquery**

```
$_CFG_PROCESSORFILE = "http://localhost/Gene/IMEXporter/include/IMEXporter_processor.php";

$("#csv_dedupe").live("click", function(e) {
    file_name = 'C:\\server\\xampp\\Gene\\IMEXporter\\include\\files\\' + $("#IMEXp_import_var-uploadFile-file").val();
    $.post($_CFG_PROCESSORFILE, {"task": "csv_dupe", "file_name": file_name}, function(data) {
        alert("success");
    }, "json")
});
```

**PHP**

```
if ($task == "csv_dupe") {
$input_filename = $_REQUEST["file_name"];
$output_filename = $_REQUEST["file_name"];

$input_file = fopen($input_filename, 'r');
$output_file = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
$email_addresses = array();
// Read the header
$headers = fgetcsv($input_file, 0);
fputcsv($output_file, $headers);
// Flip it so it becomes name => ID
$headers = array_flip($headers);

// Read every row
while (($row = fgetcsv($input_file, 0)) !== FALSE)
{
    $email = $row[$headers['email']];
    // Do we already have this email address?
    if (isset($email_addresses[$email]))
        continue;

    // Mark this email as being found
    $email_addresses[$email] = true;
    // Write it to the output
    fputcsv($output_file, $row);
}
```

}

I cant seem to figure out why its not working and what I am doing wrong. Any ideas would appreciated.

**EDIT**
**Fixed but new errors show**

I received some errors when the request returned.

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\server\xampp\htdocs\Gene\IMEXporter\include\IMEXporter_processor.php on line 45

Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\server\xampp\htdocs\Gene\IMEXporter\include\IMEXporter_processor.php on line 47
"success"

Comment: You are no echoing any answer from PHP, try adding at the end : echo json_encode("success");

Comment: I added "echo json_encode("success");" to the end of the if clause, right before the last bracket, in the php, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to change from json to jsonp as it seems like its cross-domain post..

Comment: I was able to pull out some errors from the console. this is what it reports

Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\server\xampp\htdocs\Gene\IMEXporter\include\IMEXporter_processor.php on line 45

Warning: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in C:\server\xampp\htdocs\Gene\IMEXporter\include\IMEXporter_processor.php on line 47
"success"

Answer (score 0):

Found someone with a similar problem [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#87196).

Add line before opening a file

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
```

fgetcsv() is returning a boolean value of "false" when it reaches the end of the file. From php-manual:

```
fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.
```

references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php
- [php fgetcsv returning all lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539053/php-fgetcsv-returning-all-lines)